# $.ajax() success and error not getting called

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url: "captcheck.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: "code="+captcha.val(),        
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {              
        if (html==1) {  
            captcha.removeClass('validation-error',animateSpeed);
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            captcha.addClass('validation-error',animateSpeed);
            return false;
        }    
    },      
    error: function(httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("status=" + textStatus + ",error=" + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Now this is a pretty simple ajax function, but neither is its success getting called nor error, i checked the XHR with response on the firebug and its perfect, still neither success nor error getting called. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way I can test your code on my end, but I will give my two cents:

- Add the 'complete' callback function to help you figure out if there is any syntax errors in your code.. From jQuery document: "'Complete' is a function to be called when the request finishes (after success and  error callbacks are executed)"
- Use simple codes like `alert('str')` and `console.log('str')` inside callback functions for debugging.

Btw, do `addClass` and `removeClass` support more than one parameter? I can't find it in the  [official document](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the `if (html==1)` since success callback return string, you should try `if (html==="1")`